# error with R.drawable.icon ; icon cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

There comes error with the auto-generated code section: R.drawable. Please suggest solution for the error with:

R.drawable.icon :- icon cannot be resolved or is not a field

The .java file possessing this error looks like this:

```
package net.learn2develop.UsingNotifications;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DisplayNotifications extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //---get the notification ID for the notification; 
        // passed in by the MainActivity---
        int notifID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("NotifID");

        //---PendingIntent to launch activity if the user selects 
        // the notification---
        Intent i = new Intent("net.learn2develop.AlarmDetails");
        i.putExtra("NotifID", notifID);  

        PendingIntent detailsIntent = 
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)
            getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notif = new Notification(
            R.drawable.icon,
            "Time's up!",
            System.currentTimeMillis());

        CharSequence from = "AlarmManager - Time's up!";
        CharSequence message = "This is your alert, courtesy of the AlarmManager";        
        notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, detailsIntent);

        //---100ms delay, vibrate for 250ms, pause for 100 ms and
        // then vibrate for 500ms---
        notif.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500};        
        nm.notify(notifID, notif);
        //---destroy the activity---
        finish();
    }
}
```

The manifest file also indicates it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="net.learn2develop.UsingNotifications"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>        
        <activity android:name=".AlarmDetails" 
            android:label="Details of the alarm">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="net.learn2develop.AlarmDetails" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".DisplayNotification" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="net.learn2develop.DisplayNotification" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: So, did you put an image resources (e.g. named "icon.png") in one of the drawable folders of your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if under the dir gen there's a file called R.java.
If so open it and checks if there's an attribute called icon.

It could be you moved your project or copied something from other projects.
In any cases you can remove manually the file under gen and let Eclipse recreate them.
If not you can go under Projects and then Clean chosing your project.
It should work.

Answer (score 3):

I just thought I would add a quick additional answer to this topic. I am very new to Android development and had found that one of my classes was not compiling as it could not find any of my drawable attributes. In the end I tracked the problem down to the fact that the class was importing `android.R` (automatically added to the imports list by Eclipse). As soon as that line was taken out, the class compiled.